# Result of expression 'this.getURL'[undefined] is not a function

Tags: javascript

When i call a method directly without a setInterval the function works correctly

```
slider.prototype.onTouchEnd = function(e){
    clearInterval(this.inter);
    this.getURL(this.url + '/' + this.eid.id  + '/' + this.currX);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

putting the same function in a setInterval give me following error:
Result of expression 'this.getURL'[undefined] is not a function

```
slider.prototype.onTouchStart = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.inter = setInterval("this.getURL('www.google.com')",100);
}
```

the code of getURL is:

```
slider.prototype.getURL = function(url){
    console.log(url);
    verzoek=new XMLHttpRequest();
    verzoek.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(verzoek.readyState==4) {
            if(verzoek.status==200) {
                var data=verzoek.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    verzoek.open("GET", url, true);
    verzoek.send(null);
}
```

the this.inter is created in the constructor

```
var slider = function(eid){
    ...
    this.inter = null;  
}
```

I tried so many things but it keeps failing.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a real function to `setInterval`, you are currently passing a string.

If you change it to:

```
slider.prototype.onTouchStart = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = this;
    this.inter = setInterval(function(){that.getURL('www.google.com');},100);
}
```

Does it work?